# Discord.js how to assign person sending the command to a variable

Tags: discord.js

My question may sound odd I apologize. But im working on a command for my bot that changes your own nickname when you type '>callme newNickName'.

```
case 'callme':
        let nick = args[1];
        setNickname(nick); //this is where i am stuck
        break;
```

I'm not sure how to define the person who sent the command so that their own nickname gets changed accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that your bot has the appropriate permissions to manage and change nicknames otherwise this will not work.

You should be able to do it like this:

```
if (message.content.includes('callme')) {
    if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission('MANAGE_NICKNAMES')) {
        return message.channel.send('Not allowed');
    }
    message.member.setNickname(message.content.replace('changeNick ', ''));
}
```

Please see the GuildMember documentation for more detail: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=setNickname